# How to pass a value over a channel without borrow checking issues?

Tags: rust, lifetime, channel, borrow-checker

In the following code, I understand why I'm not allowed to do this(I think), but I'm not sure what to do to fix the issue.  I'm simply trying to perform an action based upon an incoming message on a UDPSocket.  However, by sending the reference to the slice over the channel, I get a problem where the buffer doesn't live long enough.  I'm hoping for some suggestions because I don't know enough about Rust to move forward.

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        match rx.try_recv() {
            Ok(msg) => {
                match msg {
                    "begin" => // run an operation
                    "end" | _ => // kill the previous operation
                }
            }
            Err = { //Error Handling }
        }
    }

    // start listener
    let socket: UdpSocket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:9001")?;

    loop {
        let mut buffer = [0; 100];
        let (length, src_address) = socket.recv_from(&mut buffer)?;
        println!("Received message of {} bytes from {}", length, src_address);

        let cmd= str::from_utf8(&buffer[0..length]).unwrap();  // <- buffer does not live long enough
        println!("Command: {}", cmd);

        tx.send(cmd).expect("unable to send message to channel");  // Error goes away if I remove this.
    }

}
```

Comment: `str::from_utf8` just check if the `&[u8]` is valid utf8, and cast it to `&str`, so in your case `cmd` is a `&str` that is borrowed from `buffer`. if you want to send it you will need to turn it into a string. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b6a290c8e4beffc086ff6248193b8b14)

Comment: what you can do to avoid creating a string and have to allocate stuff, you can move your match statement in the loop and send an Enum that notify your other thread what to do: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4990029e97e3e8e4559de54d221e0e46). The match statement will probably be faster than creating the string.

Comment: I like that enum option.  Great suggestion.  Please feel free to make that an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should **avoid sending non-owned values over a channel** since its unlikely that a lifetime would be valid for both the sender and receiver (its possible to do, but you'd have to plan for it).

In this situation, you're trying to share pass `&str` across the channel but since it just references `buffer` which isn't guaranteed to exist whenever `rx` receives it, you get a borrow checking error. You would probably want to convert the `&str` into an *owned* `String` and pass that over the channel:

```
use std::net::UdpSocket;
use std::sync::mpsc;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
        match rx.recv().as_deref() {
            Ok("begin") => { /* run an operation */ }
            Ok("end") => { /* kill the previous operation */ }
            Ok(_) => { /* unknown */ }
            Err(_) => { break; }
        }
    });

    let socket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:9001").unwrap();
    loop {
        let mut buffer = [0; 100];
        let (length, src_address) = socket.recv_from(&mut buffer).unwrap();
        let cmd = std::str::from_utf8(&buffer[0..length]).unwrap();
        tx.send(cmd.to_owned()).unwrap();
    }
}
```

---

As proposed in the comments, you can avoid allocating a string if you parse the value into a known value for an `enum` and send that across the channel instead:

```
use std::net::UdpSocket;
use std::sync::mpsc;

enum Command {
    Begin,
    End,
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
        match rx.recv() {
            Ok(Command::Begin) => { /* run an operation */ }
            Ok(Command::End) => { /* kill the previous operation */ }
            Err(_) => { break; }
        }
    });

    let socket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:9001").unwrap();
    loop {
        let mut buffer = [0; 100];
        let (length, src_address) = socket.recv_from(&mut buffer).unwrap();
        let cmd = std::str::from_utf8(&buffer[0..length]).unwrap();
        let cmd = match cmd {
            "begin" => Command::Begin,
            "end" => Command::End,
            _ => panic!("unknown command")
        };
        tx.send(cmd).unwrap();
    }
}
```